# How to use custom UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have subclass of `UINavigationBar`.

```
@interface MyNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
```

Made some changes and now want that my application `NavigationController` would use it:

```
 _navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
 [_window addSubview:[_navigationController view]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I want that _**navigationController** would have **MyNavigationBar**

How this could be done ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a xib with a `UINavaigationController` in it. You can then select the `navigationBar` in Interface Builder and change the class to your subclass of `UINavigationBar`.

[image]

Then to make this a little easier to instantiate I add a category to `UINavigationController like:

```
@interface UINavigationController (DSCNavigationController)

+ (UINavigationController *)dsc_navigationControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController;

@end

@implementation UINavigationController (DSCNavigationController)

+ (UINavigationController *)dsc_navigationControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController;
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DSCNavigationController" owner:nil options:nil];

    NSAssert(1 == [topLevelObjects count], @"DSCNavigationController should have one top level object");

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    NSAssert([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]], @"Should have a UINavigationController");

    [navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:NO];

    return navigationController;
}

@end
```

At the top of the class that uses it makes sure to import the category in my case it looks like

```
#import "UINavigationController+DSCNavigationController"
```

Then using it looks something like

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController  alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [UINavigationController dsc_navigationControllerWithRootViewController:myViewController];
```

Comment: Worked. But this don't work the  [self.navigationController pushViewController:sendMsg animated:YES];

Comment: What class are you calling this from? Check that `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);` is not null

Comment: Yes it is null. I am calling from myViewController

Comment: It shouldn't be null... your view controller is not inside a navigationController

Comment: Hmm but i am calling from RootViewController and it is null. What may be solution for this ?

Comment: When you do `self.window.rootViewController = // ...` you should be setting it to the navigationController not the rootViewController of the navigationController

Answer (score 1):

UINavigationController has a read-only property

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UINavigationBar *navigationBar
```

since it is read-only you have to subclass UINavigationBar and override this property or make it read-write.E.g. :

```
MyNaviagtionBar *myBar = [[MyNavigationBar alloc] init];
_navigationController.navigationBar = mybar;
```

Or subclassing:

MyNavigationController.h

```
@class MyNavigationBar;

@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController
@property(nonatomic, strong) MyNavigationBar *navigationBar;
@end
```

MyNavigationController.m

```
@implementation MyNavigationController
@synthesize navigationBar = _navigationBar;
@end
```

And then change

```
_navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
```

to

```
_navigationController = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
```

Comment: I added this to interface:

But when i try to do what you showed i get this:
Assigment to read only property

Comment: I can't do this it fire an error @synthesize navigationBar = _navigationBar;

Property 'navigationBar' attempting to use ivar '_navigationBar' declared in super class 'UINavigationController'