# Change UINavigationBar with IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

I'm trying to change a `UINavigationController` navigation bar to my custom navigation bar (subclass of UINavigationBar) with IB.
So I have a xib file with a `UINavigationController`, but when I stand on the navigation bar and go to the inspector to change it's class, It shows me a `UINavigationItem` class not `UINavigationBar`, and I can't choose my custom navigation bar.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I found the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006011/how-to-use-custom-uinavigationbar)

Only after I tapped on the "Show Document Outline" button (the rounded arrow at the left bottom), I could find the navigationBar under the navigation controller, and change his class.