# Custom UINavigationBar disappears when override SizeThatFits() - MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

I am trying to subclass UINavigationBar, and use this in my UINavigationController by setting the navigation bar's class in Interface Builder. (Similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007896/139388 )

When I override SizeThatFits() the NavigationBar no longer appear in my app. If I comment out the override and re-run the app, the navigation bar appears properly.

```
[Register ("MyNavigationBar")]
public partial class MyNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
{
    public MyNavigationBar (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    // If I comment out this method, the navigation bar appears properly
    public override SizeF SizeThatFits (SizeF size)
    {
        return base.SizeThatFits (size);
    }
}
```

Now, I would expect that overriding a method that merely returns the base implementation would not modify the behaviour of the class, but I'm not familiar enough with iOS and MonoTouch to understand if this is expected/undefined behaviour, and what I can do about it.

Some things I noticed:

- If I breakpoint on SizeThatFits(), the 'size' parameter is empty (Width=Height=0).
- If I override LayoutSubviews() and breakpoint on that, the Bounds and Frame properties have funny Heights (e.g.. 9.035957E-33) whenever the SizeThatFits() method is overridden, but the heights are normal (44) when SizeThatFits() is not overridden.

I am using MonoTouch, and my app is built as Storyboard in Xcode.

Any assistance appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this happens only on the simulator, the device or both ? and what version of MonoTouch are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

Setting the width explicitly failed for me, but using the value of the superview's width worked:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    return CGSizeMake(self.superview.bounds.size.width, 60.0f); 
}
```

Since we don't have much influence over the UINavigationBar's frame or autoresizing masks, I feel a little less gross about querying the superview for details--but if someone has a better solution, please share.