# connect custom navigation bar outlet to view in IB

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have drug a navigation bar onto my view in IB.  Then changed the class of the NavigationBar object to a custom navigation bar subclass.

How do I connect my outlet for the bar to be set as a navigationBar?  When I attempt to ctrl + drag to my File's Owner to create the outlet, the only option is 'View.'

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to make it the navigation bar in a navigationController? If so check this answer for a rough idea of where to start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006011/how-to-use-custom-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `.h`

```
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
```

If you want some changes on your `navigationBar` from your code then your have to make `IBOutlet`.

Comment: I'm actually looking at a few examples of this done and they didn't add anything into the .h.  Which was the cause for the question.. apparently u can do this all in IB.  And I would like to know how.

Comment: @JesseDurham, it's not true that you can do it all in IB. Where did you get that idea? You need an outlet to connect it to, and that has to be created in code.

Comment: my mistake, the files i was looking at were actually subclasses of another view which had the nav bar outlet declared.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of outlet for Custom Naviation bar. Just select navigation bar on storyboard & in inspector window write the name of your custom class

[image]

Comment: if you want to set title and color of navigation bar?

Comment: @Rajneesh071: if you are customizing the Nav bar then you can do all things there in custom class

Comment: if in one viewController i want red color and in other i want green color of navigation bar then?